# Isn't it possible to have multiple buttons  along with a submit button? 

Tags: 7, forms

I have a simple Drupal 7 form, with 3 dropdown select lists and a submission button. I want to add another button to the form which does some function (but not submitting the form). I want to bypass the validation part for the form and directly run the submission handler of that button.

The button I am using is the following one.

```
$form['my_fieldset']['click'] = array(
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => 'click me',
  '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
  '#executes_submit_callback' => FALSE,
  '#submit' => array('my_module_click_submit'),
);
```

FYI, all the select lists have `#required=>TRUE`, and `#type=>'submit'` for the button also doesn't work.

When I click it, it shows the error about the fields being required. How can I avoid that error, avoid validation handlers are run, and just run the code in `my_module_click_submit()`?

Also, I dont know why, but even if I fill the entire form and then click this button, the page just gets refreshed and `my_module_click_submit()` does NOT run. What's wrong?

I haven't put anything fancy inside `my_module_click_submit()`; I just wanted to see if it works. The submission handler I am trying is the following one.

```
function my_module_click_submit($form,&$form_state) {
  drupal_set_message('Click me button is clicked');
}
```

Comment: have you tried `'#type' => '#submit',` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jaypan](http://drupal.org/user/324696) gave me the answer.

> 1. Required checks happen irregardless of validation - they happen before any other validation even occurs.
> 2. You cannot skip the default _validation() function, it is always executed
> 3. When you choose limit_validation_errors(), anything that is not part of that array is not submitted.
>
> As such, you will want to explicitly declare your submit and validate functions for the original submit button, and leave the second button as-is, using the default submit and validate functions:
>
> ```
> function some_form($form, &$form_state) {
>   // Form definition not shown.
>   $form['submit1'] = array(
>     '#type' => 'submit',
>     '#value' => t('Submit 1'),
>     '#validate' => array('my_explicit_validate'),
>     '#submit' => array('my_explicit_submit'),
>   );
>
>   $form['submit2'] = array(
>     '#type' => 'submit',
>     '#value' => t('Submit 2'),
>   );
>
>   return $form;
> }
>
> // my_form_validate is not created, since we don't want to validate the second submit button, but we do want the submit function.
> function my_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
>   // You need to check which submit button was pushed, as this function
>   // will be run for both buttons, but you only want do something if it was the 
>   // secondbutton.
>   if($form_state['values']['op'] == $form_state['values']['submit2']) {
>     // Second submit button's submit function.
>   }
> }
>
> function my_explicit_validate($form, &$form_state) {
>   // Validation for the first submit button.
> }
>
> function my_explicit_submit($form, &$form_state) {
>   // First submit button's submit function.
> }
> ```
>
> To deal with your required issue, you will need to not set `#required => TRUE` for the elements, and check them manually in your validation function (the function explicitly declared for the first button). If you want to have the required marks, I think you can manually add them to the element title, or you can override the theme function for those elements and manually add them there.

Answer (score 2):

You are correctly using the `#limit_validation_errors` property; [the documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#limit_validation_errors) clearly states that setting it to an empty array avoids any validation being done. Even reading what reported for [form_set_error()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), I cannot find anything that would explain the behavior you are observing.

> The standard `form_set_error()` behavior can be changed if a button provides the `#limit_validation_errors` property. Multistep forms not wanting to validate the whole form can set `#limit_validation_errors` on buttons to limit validation errors to only certain elements. For example, pressing the "Previous" button in a multistep form should not fire validation errors just because the current step has invalid values. If `#limit_validation_errors` is set on a clicked button, the button must also define a `#submit` property (may be set to an empty array). Any `#submit` handlers will be executed even if there is invalid input, so extreme care should be taken with respect to any actions taken by them. This is typically not a problem with buttons like "Previous" or "Add more" that do not invoke persistent storage of the submitted form values. Do not use the `#limit_validation_errors` property on buttons that trigger saving of form values to the database.
>
> The `#limit_validation_errors` property is a list of "sections" within `$form_state['values']` that must contain valid values. Each "section" is an array with the ordered set of keys needed to reach that part of `$form_state['values']` (i.e., the `#parents` property of the element).

I can only think of a collateral effect of setting the `#limit_validation_errors`, and the `#executes_submit_callback` properties. The latter is causing the submission handler not to be called for your button; when you set it to `FALSE`, the button doesn't submit the form, which means the submission handler for that button is not being called.