# How to implement a cancel button with required elements

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form in which I have added a cancel button which looks like this:

```
$form['cancel_button'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Cancel'),
  '#name' => 'cancel',
  '#access' => TRUE,
  '#submit' => array('mymodule_cancel'),
  '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);
```

This form has required elements in it as well and what is causing the problem. I thought that by having the #limit_validation_errors statement would prevent the required elements check, but that is not happening. How do I prevent the required elements from being checked?

**EDIT:** I found this answer on a different question [Isn't it possible to have multiple buttons  along with a submit button?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28313)

This would explain the behaviour I am seeing but it seems to contradict the Drupal documentation about limiting error checking. This would really screw up people who want to save a draft of a form that has required fields. I am pretty sure I have seen this done before, so there must be away around this.

Comment: If it's just a simple redirect, I'd just add #markup as a regular link.

Answer (score -1):

You can make something like this in your function validate :

```
function FORM_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
if ($form_state['values']['op'] == 'cancel')
{
 ///  Do something
/// drupal_goto() for example
}
}
```

Comment: Never depend on this 'op'.  It's translated and raw value. Use the trigger_element from $form_state.